# Table values being cut-off by table lines

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

Is there a way in the SSRS table component to avoid that the values get cut-off by the lines of the table. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should format your label so that there is a background color of white (instead of default none).

Right-click on one of the labels and select **Series Label Properties**.  Select **Fill**.  By default this is set to *No Color*.  Change it to *White*.  Click **OK**.  That should take care of it!

**ADDITION**: It may be possible to write an expression to change the distance between the label and the bar.  When you select one of the labels, check out the properties window.  You would need to play around with **SmartLabels** - specifically *MaxMovingDistance* and *MinMovingDistance*.  You would need to have chart lines at specific intervals and then build the expression around the value being within one of those intervals.

I know that is short on details, but hopefully the idea sketch gets you started in the right direction!

Comment: Click by click details would be really helpful. Specially for future readers.

Comment: The downside to this solution is that parts of the bars are hidden by the label background.

Comment: Ah - I see.  You'd prefer to move the label... you can write an expression to change the distance of the label from the bar.  You might could tweak that a bit... I'll add some thoughts to my answer above